# android unable to find app on play store with name

Tags: java, android, google-play

I am unable to find my app on play store even with putting its exact name. but while I put  name without space then play store shows it on top of the searched list.

Can anyone explain what is the issue and how can I get rid of this?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the search function also considers the package name while searching like com.whatever.whatever. let your app gain popularity then you app will come on top of search result even when you put spaces

Comment: yeah you are right.. my app is coming up with increasing number of downloads.... thanks :)

Comment: can you tell me how to use flurry video ads in my app.. can you provide me the code to integrate flurry clips(videos) in my app..

Comment: i have no idea, start another question or search for similar questions on this site. Also if you are satisfied by an answer to question that you have asked, you should click on the tick mark to the bottomleft of the answer to "accept" it as the correct answer.